# Would Batman have committed genocide and killed his friends to gain victory?

Tags: dc, batman, justice-league, morality

In [Superman/Batman Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Batman:_Apocalypse):

Batman arms the hellspores and issues Darkseid an ultimatum: Release Kara, or he'll let them destroy Apokolips. As Batman was separated from the other heroes, and Darkseid has highly advanced surveillance technology, it is clear nobody else held the means to disarm them. Considering that he refuses to back down even after being severely injured when Darkseid smashes him through a wall, it seems clear that Batman isn't bluffing.

[image]

Even Darkseid is impressed with his resolve. After realizing that he's lost, he smiles and says:

> Well played. Had the Kryptonian or the Amazon taken that gamble, they
>   would have lost. They do not have the strength of character to
>   destroy an entire planet to achieve success.
>
> But you, a human? You kill your own kind to win battles. An admirable
>   quality. Take the girl. I will make no move against her.

I find it surprising that Batman would resort to such extreme measures. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: I got the impression while watching it that Batman was bluffing. Darkseid believed him because of humanity's reputation. It's been a while since I've see in it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he had no other choice he might have. The other heroes know what they've signed up for and are all willing to lay their own lives down for the greater good and Batman knows this. Every time I've seen Batman truly backed up against a corner he has no limit. He only has repercussions when he's Batman, if he has to stop being Batman (like dies) he'll do whatever he deems necessary.

For instance, there's a time when the Joker does something so bad Batman has had enough. (I wont say where, spoilers) He pretty much turns to the Joker and says, "I should have done this sooner" and he breaks one of his biggest rules and snaps The Jokers neck and proceeds to turn himself in for murder. Of course, this was not canon.

Side note: It should be mentioned Batman probably knows Superman, and Martian Manhunter would definitely survive, and Green Lantern and Flash probably would (Depends on the writers)